# Is there a way use SMB protocol without a router?

Tags: networking, lan, file-sharing, smb

I'd like to transfer files from Windows to Ubuntu, with direct LAN cable, I previously got it working using router (wireless), but I can't get it working if I connect them directly using LAN cable without router.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://techwiser.com/how-to-connect-pc-to-pc-lan-cable/

Answer (score 2):

You need either a crossover cable or a dumb hub or some other networking hardware with rj45 ports between the two devices. A crossover cable is a specific LAN cable that crosses the 1 and 2 wire pair with the 3 and 6 pair.  This mimics what a switch or hub does when it comes to transferring data.  There are other crossover schemes (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable ) but generally if you buy or make a crossover cable this is what you are looking for in your situation.  Some newer devices will do this automatically with an automatic MDI/MDI-X configuration but it is up to the manufacturer to include this feature.

Comment: Then I can use SMB protocol?

Comment: once connected, you can use any protocol you want; invent one even....

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it

Comment: Gigabit connections will work with a straight through cable. Automatic crossover detection is part if the spec.